# Adding an UIImage to a UITableViewCell for "State Touched"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

What's the best way of adding an image for the touch state in a `UITableViewCell`?

I know how to set the `cell.selectionStyle` but I actually need to add an image (a different one for each row) just when the user is touching it (and it pushes the new view in) Like a "Button State Touched".

What's the best way of achieving this? I tried with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

Or would I have to do it inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a custom `UITableViewCell` and use the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchedBegan:touched withEvent:event];
    // ... display image 2, hide image 1
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchedEnded:touched withEvent:event];
    // ... display image 1, hide image 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need both:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For the didSelectRow, you need to store the current selected cell index. Then you call [tableView reloadData]

Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you need to set `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_here"];`